# amphtml tag shows error "Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP"

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, amp-html

I have run t a blog (blogger). I have two version of my blog which are:

1. www.filmsbit.com (non amp but responsive)
2. m.filmsbit.com (amp).

according to amp validator, i use amphtml tag in head for my non-amp blog
by using javascript. code are :

```
<script>
    var pageurl = '<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>';
    var amplink = document.createElement("link");
    amplink.href = pageurl.replace('www','m');
    amplink.rel = 'amphtml';
    document.head.appendChild(amplink);
</script>
```

Result in non amp like this:

```
<link href="http://m.filmsbit.com/2019/03/ajay-devgns-de-de-pyaar-de-first-look.html" rel="amphtml">
```

after that, in my amp blog i have use canonical tag in head for non amp link. like this

```
<link href='http://www.filmsbit.com/2019/03/ajay-devgns-de-de-pyaar-de-first-look.html' rel='canonical'/>
```

After setup all tag, I have checked my non amp link in https://search.google.com/test/amp

Result shows. Non-AMP link Submitted. But its linked tag has AMP version.
CLICK to SEE RESULT LINKED AMP VERSION.

After Clicked on link its shows an error "Indexing Error - Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP"

But when i checked my amp link (http://m.filmsbit.com/2019/03/ajay-devgns-de-de-pyaar-de-first-look.html) directly in amp checker its said "AMP Validate"

Can Some One Help me about this.

Comment: You don't have to check non amp pages on 'https://search.google.com/test/amp' this is for check the amp validation only.

Comment: friend i know that, i have use amphtml tag in non amp site. and in amp site i have used canonical tag of non amp site. pls read again what i have told in question

Answer (score 0):

Check your

```
<link ref='canonical' ...>
```

in your AMP page. Needs to point to your canonical non-amp page. Your current setting is pretty messed up. I cannot be sure this is the root cause but worth it to clean up.